# Sharepoint List Setting option is not available though permission is set

Tags: sharepoint, list

My login account is given the permission of full scope, designer and admin for this site. My account is also involved in other groups which have only limited access like contributor. Now, I can't see the "Setting" tab when I open a list. Only "New" and "Action" is available to access. How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions can be different at different levels: you may have greater permissions for a site than you do for a specific list.  It's possible, for example, to completely cut off your own access to a list on your own site. (Only a Site Collection Administrator is immune to this scenario, at least for SharePoint 2003 and 2007; they always enjoy "Full Control" permissions, period.)

I'd find another party with "Full Control" permission on the site, and ask them to check the list (not the site's) permissions and see if you're access is limited on that list.

Another option may be to look at the user security reports for the site.  Under Site Settings, see if there's options to report site permissions, including whether your own permissions are restricted on any lists within the site.

(Disclaimer: I worked heavily with SP 2003 and 2007 awhile ago, so TBD how accurate these tips are for 2010.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct privilege settings of the list (or the library / sub-site contains it).

It's possible you have full control of the site, but have limited access to its sub-site when you dont use inheriting permission levels